# Bootstrap 4 <h3> with part of the text in a smaller font

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a bootstrappy way of doing this? I want an

#### ...

to include in it a bit of detailed text in a smaller font. Previously I did this:

```
<h3>The beginning of the story
   <small>Where we meet the hero</small>
</h3>
```

But that now pnly makes the  stuff thinner not smaller. Do I have to go to css for this?

Comment: could you also add an example of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another [typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/typography/) class on a `span` inside the heading. Like `h6` for example...

```
<h3>The beginning of the story
    <span class="h6">Where we meet the hero</span>
</h3>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/wo2wdZgJEs)

Comment: Beautiful. I had tried to embed an h6 in the h3 and didn’t get what I wanted. Thanks!